# column name as variable in sql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table that contains 4 columns, A, B, C, and D. 
I need to access those fields dynamically i.e., instead of saying Table.col_A , I need to say Table.x where x can have the value of any of the columns A or B or C or D. I am getting x from the join with another table.

Comment: Somewhat depends if it is just four fields, or does it need to be a dynamically changing list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE another_table.field
           WHEN 'A' THEN main_table.field_A
           WHEN 'B' THEN main_table.field_B
           WHEN 'C' THEN main_table.field_C
           WHEN 'D' THEN main_table.field_D
           ELSE NULL
       END, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Stored Procedure, you could construct the query with `CONCAT`, `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` it.

But...  The error you are getting may be a wake-up call.  Why do you need multiple tables instead of a single table?   By moving to a single table you would probably need to add a column to distinguish which subset you are interested in.  Also adjust the `PRIMARY KEY` and other indexes as needed.

Comment: I see what you are saying. the problem is that I am getting column name dynamically.

Comment: You would pass the column name into the SP as an argument.